# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted + Trigger Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

First lets be clear I am working on a homework Assignment, Its the second to last chapter of the semester, it is over Stored procedures, functions, and trigger.  I've got all the functions and procedure questions done but I am struggling with triggers.  For this question I am try to create a trigger that will not let me update a column in a table called DiscountPercent if the value is either > 100 or < 0.  Also if the value is between 0 and 1, like say its .2 then It should multiply that number by a hundred to make the value 20.  When I test it with an update statement I get the following error...

> Procedure Products_UPDATE, Line 115
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Here is my code for the trigger...

```
CREATE TRIGGER Products_UPDATE
    ON Products
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
    DECLARE @DiscountPercent DECIMAL(5,2)
    SET @DiscountPercent = (SELECT DiscountPercent FROM Products)

IF @DiscountPercent < 0 OR @DiscountPercent > 100
    PRINT 'Number must be between 0 and 100'
ELSE IF @DiscountPercent BETWEEN 0 And 1
    UPDATE Products
    SET DiscountPercent = @DiscountPercent * 100
```

and this is the code I used to test it...

```
UPDATE Products
SET DiscountPercent = 0
WHERE ProductID = 17
```

Any idea on why I am getting this error?

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

A trigger fires once per statement, which can affect many rows.  Use the `inserted` table to identify the rows updated and use set-based queries instead of scalar variables.  Below is an example.  Substitute your actual primary key for `ProductID`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Products_UPDATE ON Products
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
    IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
                FROM    inserted
                WHERE   DiscountPercent < 0
                        OR DiscountPercent > 100 )
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR('Number must be between 0 and 100', 16, 1);
            ROLLBACK;
        END;

    UPDATE  Products
    SET     DiscountPercent = DiscountPercent * 100
    WHERE   ProductID IN ( SELECT   ProductID
                           FROM     inserted
                           WHERE    DiscountPercent BETWEEN 0 AND 1 );
GO
```

Comment: How we can be sure of that data from inserted table will be same that he is looking from query(SELECT DiscountPercent FROM Products)?

Comment: @PareshJadhav, the `inserted` table is a subset of rows in Products, containing logical copies of rows modified by the `UPDATE` query. The original query in question had no correlation to `inserted` so every row in the Products table was processed each time the trigger fired, which was not the intent according to the stated purpose of the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Products table has more than one row. so u need to add filter to get the required row.

```
set @d = (select top 1  DiscountPercent FROM Products)
select @d = DiscountPercent FROM Products
```

try something like this.

```
DECLARE @DiscountPercent DECIMAL(5, 2)

SELECT @DiscountPercent = DiscountPercent,
       @id = ProductID
FROM   inserted

IF @DiscountPercent < 0
    OR @DiscountPercent > 100
  PRINT 'Number must be between 0 and 100'
ELSE IF @DiscountPercent BETWEEN 0 AND 1
  UPDATE Products
  SET    DiscountPercent = @DiscountPercent * 100
  WHERE  ProductID = @id
```

Or

```
UPDATE A
SET    A.DiscountPercent = B.DiscountPercent * 100
FROM   Products A
       JOIN inserted B
         ON A.ID = B.id
```

Comment: top 1 needs order by isn't it? probably order by on productid to get last inserted entry

Comment: Yes!! thats y i mentioned to add filter. even top 1 is not the answer here.

Comment: Ok I think I know what you guys mean, my declaration SET @DiscountPercent = (SELECT DiscountPercent FROM Products) is returning all the rows not just a particular row, maybe if I ad a where clause to that?  You guys have got me on the right track I think.

Comment: @user3530547 - yes u need to get the productid in where clause.

Comment: Thank You guys, I got it execute without error, but now when I run my update the trigger doesn't execute, I just tried updating a row with a negative number as the DiscountPercent which should of trigger the PRINT statement, but it did not.  I also tried updating with a value of .2 so that the trigger would multiply it by 100 to give me a value of 20 but that also didn't work.  But I am getting closer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 DECLARE @DiscountPercent DECIMAL(5,2)
    SET @DiscountPercent = (SELECT DiscountPercent FROM Products)
```

The error are you facing is comes due to you are set the value in @discount percent is variable set operator set one value to another but if would you do this through select operator then if multiple values are comes then it by default take first value so you can do it through this way also.
you have to change  `SET @DiscountPercent = (SELECT DiscountPercent FROM Products)`  TO

```
SELECT  @DiscountPercent = DiscountPercent FROM Products
```